# In which case $M_1 \times N \cong M_2 \times N \Rightarrow M_1 \cong M_2$ is true?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Usually for modules $M_1,M_2,N$
$$M_1 \times N \cong M_2 \times N \Rightarrow M_1 \cong M_2$$
is wrong. I'm just curious, but are there any cases or additional conditions where it gets true?

James B.

Comment: Hm... if $M_1$, $M_2$ and $N$ are free and finitely generated over a ring with the IBN, it holds true.

Comment: This is a **very hard** question: For example, let $R=k\[x_1,\ldots,x_n\]$. If $P$ is projective module of finite rank and $P\oplus R^n\cong  R^{n+m}$, then $P\cong R^m\ \ldots$ But this is the Serre's Conjecture!

Answer (score 7):

A standard result in this direction is the Krull-Schmidt Theorem:

**Theorem (Krull-Schmidt for modules)** *Let $E$ be a nonzero module that has both ACC and DCC on submodules (that is, $E$ is both artinian and noetherian). Then $E$ is a direct sum of (finitely many) indecomposable modules, and the direct summands are unique up to a permutation and isomorphism.*

In particular:

**Corollary.** If $M_1$, $M_2$, and $N$ are both noetherian and artinian, and $M_1\times N \cong M_2\times N$, then $M_1\cong M_2$.

*Proof.* Both $M_1\times N$ and $M_2\times N$ satisfy the hypothesis of the Krull-Schmidt Theorem; decompose $M_1$, $M_2$, and $N$ into a direct sum of indecomposable modules. The uniqueness clause of Krull-Schmidt yields the isomorphism of $M_1$ with $M_2$. $\Box$

Answer (score 5):

I recommend *A Crash Course on stable range, cancellation,
substitution and exchange* by T.Y. Lam, 2004, which is a pretty good guide to the phenomenon.

**Update:** [Another question surfaced](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160764/theorem-of-witt-for-modules) which contains a sufficient condition for cancellation. The condition is: $\hom(M_1,N)=\hom(M_2,N)=\{0\}$.